# How to overcome "flip_done" timed out errors

Tags: system

Installed Elementary OS on Lenovo R61 laptop. Takes over 5 minutes to start. Black screen filled with flip_done timed out error messages before splash screen displayed. Once started it takes exactly one minute from the time the password is entered until the desktop is displayed.

Comment: And you are using elementary OS Juno? This is a issue with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: We need more information to help you better. Execute from terminal `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. Also go to System Settings >About, screenshot that page and add the image to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a bug. To avoid delay you can use workaround. From terminal
>   run:
>
> 1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
>
> Then add the kernel boot parameter: `video=SVIDEO-1:d`, so it will
>   look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash
>   video=SVIDEO-1:d"`
>
> 2. `sudo update-grub`
> 3. `sudo reboot`

Above answer grabbed from https://askubuntu.com/a/916112/907048

Comment: How to get to command prompt to do this if getting this while lmde is booting up?